# I can create a file but I can't read from it

Tags: bash, ssh, permissions

I've been using linux for a while, but I always had root access, so permission problems were no big deal. But now I don't have root access and it's driving me mad.

I have a ssh access to a web server. This means I have access to my user `gabitoptalentro`, and also to the `apache` user through PHP backticks. I have problems with some `tmp` folder (*not* `/tmp`). `ls -l` says this:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 gabitoptalentro toptalentro   4096 Jun 15 19:15 tmp
```

When I try to `touch` a file (`touch tmp/QQ`) to create it in this folder it works (the file is created), **but** it doesn't show up in `ls -l`. Here is the entry from **my ssh account**:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache   0 Jun 15 19:37 QQ
```

So the file actually belongs to `apache`, but `apache` can't read it.

I also tried to `chown` the whole folder to `apache`, but it won't let me (`chown: changing ownership of ...: Operation not permitted`). Wtf, it doesn't let me give my own folders to someone else?

So, do you have any idea how I can get myself out of this mess and help `apache` read it's own files?

Comment: What exactly is Apache complaining of? Copy-paste error messages. It's possible that CGI scripts are restricted to a part of the filesystem.

Comment: giving your files to someone else would be a security problem, for example if the `setuid` bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the server is set up to use access control lists, which is an extension of the normal Unix file permissions, or SELinux based roles.

You can check the ACL on the directory like this...

```
> getfacl /path/to/your/tmp
```

You should get something like this if everything is normal...

```
# file: tmp
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

If you see lines like the following...

```
user:someotheruser:---
group:someothergroup:---
```

...you are dealing with an ACL'd file/dir. As you can probably guess, this is letting you set rights for specific users and groups. You can change these (permissions allowing) with the command `setfacl`. There are also a variety of defaults possible in the ACL on the directory that would cause new files to be created with unexpected permissions.

---

If that does not do it for you, you could be dealing with role based security in SELinux. Run the command `getenforce`. If it is set to enforcing Apache will only be able to read files in the HTTP context.

```
> /usr/sbin/getenforce
Enforcing
```

You would need to `chcon` (change context) your tmp directory...

```
> chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/your/tmp
```

[Here's a good SELinux FAQ](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/faq.html)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for newly created files are set with `umask`. But the `umask` in this case looks OK.

`-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache   0 Jun 15 19:37 QQ`

Signs 2,3,4 are permissions for owner, and they are  `rw-` which means that apache can read and write these files.

Make sure you are logged as apache when you are trying to read and write.

Comment: yup, `whoami` gives me `apache`.

Comment: Ensure that user ID apache actually has the correct path to the file.  You used a relative path ("tmp/QQ") in your example.  Does the process in question have a working directory of whatever "tmp/" appears in? Does the process in question try to read the file by a fully-qualified name or something else?